# How to compress in Oracle 11gR2

Tags: oracle

I need to compress a clob column data in My table `T1_TEST`. The column name is `XML_DATA`.

```
CREATE TABLE T1_TEST(CLOB_DATA CLOB);
```

The compressed column data will be read by the .NET application and decompress it at their end.

How can i achieve this.(I know that we have got `UTL_COMPRESS.LZ_COMPRESS` and `LZ_UNCOMPRESS`) which uses a `Lempel -Ziv` alogrithm).

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

11g introduced SecureFile - the new LOB (compression, dedup, encryption)
If you need to decompress client-side, SecureFile will not help you.

```
create table t1_test 
(
        clob_data       clob
)
tablespace users
lob (clob_data)

store as securefile
(
        tablespace users
        enable storage in row
        chunk 4096
        pctversion 20
        nocache
)
/
```

Now, Oracle takes care of compression for you:

```
alter table t1_test
modify lob(clob_data)
(compress high)
/
```

[Arup Nanda wrote this great article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-securefiles-084075.html)